# Writing a Custom Condition in WSO2 CEP

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I want to extend the Wso2 CEP product in our needs and try to write a custom condition as indicated in this [official wso2 cep link](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/CEP210/Writing+Extentions+to+Siddhi).

However it says that "This is the latest, released WSO2 Complex Event Processor documentation (Version 2.1.0)." at the top of the page, it seems that it is outdated or having wrong information.

For example it says that,

> To write a custom condition, create a class extending "org.wso2.siddhi.core.executor.conditon.AbstractGenericConditionExecutor", add the SiddhiExtionsion annotation, compile that class, and add the jar file to the class path /repertory/components/lib. Then add the fully-qualified class name for the implementation class in a new line, to the siddhi.extension file located at /repertory/conf/siddhi.

(I am assuming "repertory" is "repository"). There is no file or directory in official WSO2 CEP package as "/repertory/conf/siddhi" or "siddhi.extension", (wso2cep-2.1.0).

Is there a thing that i missed in this documentation, if not, can you recommend a new documentation about to write a custom condition in WSO2 CEP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug, there is a folder called "sidddhi" in the , it needs to be "siddhi" (this is a small typo error).. Please change that directory name to "siddhi" and perform your task  ("sidddhi" to "siddhi")...

Yes.. I have corrected the doc also with the correct "repository"... Thanks for the notification...

Regards,

Mohan

Comment: when i download wso2 cep from the official site, "/repository/conf/" does not have a directory named "siddhi" or "sidddhi", but i download it again and see that there is a directory named "sidddhi", now it seems ok, thank you (however README file also still do not have any explanation about the folder "siddhi"). I just want to ask if i only copy that directory (siddhi) from newly downloaded copy to the right location, the cep that i working on will be ok?

Comment: Yes.. you can copy or just create a directory called "siddhi" in your pack and work on it...

Comment: Last copy downloaded from the official site has another bug now, the folder siddhi under the /repository/conf has a folder under it named siddhi.extension and this folder contains a file named siddhi.extension, this is wrong configuration if i use that configuration CEP engine could not see my new condition class and function. To get a success from that job siddhi.extension file must be under siddhi folder.